# How to display strings with angle brackets in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to display, literally, angle brackets in Vue. Let's say I want to display on my page, The text `"<Hello>"`. I don't want Vue to render the HTML.

What is the Vue way to do display `<hello>` on page?

I've tried, unsuccessfully:

[v-pre](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre):

```
<span v-pre>{{ <hello> }}</span>
```

adding it directly, surrounded by `{{}}`

```
{{ <hello>}}
```

Adding it directly

```
<hello>
```

Comment: Won't `&gt;hello&lt;` work?

Comment: Wrap it with brackets but with template strings. Try ```{{`<hello>`}}```

Comment: @johnmikelridzz it didn't work. It complained: ` tag <hello> has no matching end tag.`

Comment: Yup! @pai.not.pi it works!  Thank you very much. Can't believe I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you went with the suggestion of using `&gt;hello&lt;`. Which is fine, I just wanted to share another method in case someone else stumbles upon this question.

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ hello }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      hello: "<hello>"
    };
  },
};
</script>
```